# taglib-sharp: Retrieving the ChannelMode of an MP3 File

Tags: c#, taglib, taglib-sharp

I am using the taglib-sharp library in my C# Win Forms application to retrieve the duration and bit rate of MP3 files.  A code snippet follows:

```
TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(myMp3FileName);

int bitrate = tagFile.Properties.AudioBitrate;
string duration = tagFile.Properties.Duration.Hours.ToString("D2") + ":" +
                  tagFile.Properties.Duration.Minutes.ToString("D2") + ":" +
                  tagFile.Properties.Duration.Seconds.ToString("D2");
```

I would now like to also determine if the file is Mono or Stereo.  To do that, I think I need to read the ChannelMode (0 = Stereo, 1 = JointStereo, 2 = DualChannel, 3 = SingleChannel).  The only problem is that I don't know how to access it.  When I debug the code, I can see [ChannelMode in the watch window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jilzA.jpg).

Yet accessing it is proving difficult. I only got this far:

```
var codec = (((TagLib.ICodec[])tagFile.Properties.Codecs).GetValue(0));
```

When I run this, I can see [*codec* in the debugger's watch window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6BNG.jpg), and under it is *ChannelMode*.

I am inclined to think that I should just be able to read *codec.ChannelMode* at this point, but that's clearly not the right syntax.  I get this compiler error:

> Error CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'ChannelMode' and no extension method 'ChannelMode' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetValue(0)` returns a type of `object`. You will need to cast the return value to an appropriate type. In this case probably an `AudioHeader` (implements `ICodec`) which has a `ChannelMode` property. Like so

```
var codec = (AudioHeader)(((TagLib.ICodec[])tagFile.Properties.Codecs).GetValue(0));
```

Or safer

```
var codec = (((TagLib.ICodec[])tagFile.Properties.Codecs).GetValue(0)) as AudioHeader?;
if (codec != null)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Ben!  Your first solution works great!  However, for what it's worth, the second solution produces a compiler error *Error CS0077 The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('AudioHeader' is a non-nullable value type)*.  I'm a bit of a newb here, but is the solution that works somehow unsafe?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice `AudioHeader` is a struct. The first method is fine. You just want to make sure you're casting to the right type.

Comment: You can still use the second method (updated the answer) if you turn it into a `Nullable` (`... as AudioHeader?`)